# Remove a bunch of duplicate commits and references in git

Tags: git, history, rebase

I have the following situation:

```
A---B--- ... ---E---------------------------.
                                             \
                  A---B--- ... ---E---F---G---H---I--- ... ---N   master
```

I want to remove the duplicated commits from the history and remove this bad reference.

```
A---B--- ... ---E---F---G---H---I--- ... ---N   master
```

I've tried it with `git rebase -i` and remove the duplicate commits but this duplicate the commits again and results to a lot of merge conflicts.

Comment: wouw, those lines really looks like smoothly bending :P +1

Comment: Can you please explain what do you mean with "rebase makes it even worse"?, if you wanna do what you say you'll have to rewrite everything since E including H I J (even if you don't change their content, they'll have to change their parents). There's no way you can escape that. I don't know how do you even got to that point.

Comment: I've corrected the graphs, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
git checkout -b temp E
git cherry-pick F..N
git branch -D master
git branch -m temp master
```

If you don't understand what you're doing, I suggest you read the manual pages of all the commands involved. The git manpages are very nice and accessible.

Comment: I've made some mistakes in the graph. The problem is, that there are a lot of commits, not only `F G H I J` and cherry-pick can't handle a range of commits.

Comment: You can cherry-pick a range of commits. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1994463/how-to-cherry-pick-a-range-of-commits-and-merge-into-another-branch